# JTable and getInputMap - only for one key?

Tags: java, swing

Why this code doesn't work - that is, for the enter key and the delete key performs the action meant for the enter key.

```
JTable klient;

int obj=0, obj2=0;

KeyStroke klawisz = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0);
klient.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(klawisz, obj); 
klient.getActionMap().put(obj, new TabelaAkcji());

KeyStroke klawisz2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
klient.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(klawisz2, obj2); 
klient.getActionMap().put(obj2, new TabelaAkcji2());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `obj` and `obj2` are both 0.

This line

```
klient.getActionMap().put(obj2, new TabelaAkcji2());
```

will override the entry you put in previously, because the key you're using is the same as it was in your previous call.